# How Can I Correctly Route A DropDownList Selection In Razor Pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am using a SelectList as a dropdown on one of my Razor Pages to allow users to choose an AD Group. When they click the 'Set Group' button, it should display the members for that group. The page currently reloads, without any group selected.

Here is my code for the dropdown:

```html
<div>
    <hr />
    <dl class="row">
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            AD Group:
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            <select asp-for="ADGroup" asp-items="Model.ADGroups" onchange=""><option value=""></option></select>&nbsp;<a asp-page="./UpdateADGroup" asp-route-ADGroup="@Model.ADGroup" class="btn btn-outline-info btn-sm">Set Group</a>
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            Current Members:
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Members)
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

Here are, what I believe, are the pertinent parts of my model class:

```cs
private readonly RDSTestSiteContext _context;

public UpdateADGroupModel(RDSTestSiteContext context)
{
    _context = context;
}

[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
public string ADGroup { get; set; }
public List<SelectListItem> ADGroups = new List<SelectListItem>();
[BindProperty]
public Fileset Fileset { get; set; }
[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
public string Members { get; set; }

public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(long? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    Fileset = await _context.Fileset.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);

    if (Fileset == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    ADGroups.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Standard", Value = Fileset.Adgroup });
    ADGroups.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Restricted", Value = Fileset.Adgroup + "_R" });

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ADGroup))
    {
        GetGroupMembership(ADGroup);
    }

    return Page();
}
```

If I manually enter the query in the browser, for example:

*full_url?ADGroup=groupname*

Then the page loads with the selected groups members.

Can anyone help?

It would be nice to also set one of the two values as the default one too, rather than having it empty by default or duplicating one of the values by setting it in the `<option></option>` tag.

Comment: It would be cool if someone explained why I was voted down, please. Very new to asp.net core and I have tried to provide as much information as possible. Would be happy to add more detail if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tag helper executes on the the server. The `asp-route-ADGroup` attribute on the anchor tag helper is not populated with the selected group at the time the page is rendered because no group has been selected at that point.  Once the page is executed and rendered in the browser, the tag helper has no effect.

What you can do is to create a client side function that handles the `onchange` event of your dropdown:

```
function adGroupSelected(e){
    location.href = "/full_url?Group=" + e.selectedOptions[0].value;
}
```

Then assign it to the currently empty `onchange` handler in your select tag helper:

```
<select asp-for="ADGroup" asp-items="Model.ADGroups" onchange="adGroupSelected(this)">...
```

You won't need the anchor tag helper.

Comment: Hi @mike-brind, thanks for the answer. I have tested it and it works as far as activating the url is concerned, but now if the user enters an incorrect value in another field (checked by a regex - `return Page() with AddModelError()`), the url changes to `full_url?handler=blah`. I am not sure why this is now appearing.

Comment: I've sorted it. The options for the SelectList need to be set again and then the user may continue after the ModelError is returned. Thanks for your time looking at this and the javascript example - I know very little about it.